# File permissions in Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, file-permissions

I have a simple   tomcat docker file as below.

```
FROM tomcat:7
MAINTAINER ***
COPY sample.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
USER tomcat
RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat /tmp/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

When i create the docker image it will give me file permission as

```
tomcat tomcat  Dec 11 08:04 tmp
```

My sample app creates few directories inside tmp folder , i am expecting the owner to be tomcat but it looks like root. Since i am running the container as user tomcat , how to make it use tomcat user to create these.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build and run the `Dockerfile` you provided and ran into multiple errors. You are asking about the file permissions your "app" creates. So here is my starting point:

I assume that the "app" is `catalina.sh`. The process which creates your files in `/tmp/`. Since we are running the container as the user `tomcat` it automatically creates the files with the according file permissions. Have a look at the code comments below to get some more information about what is going on here.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM httpd 
# I switched the image since you would need to configure tomcat to make it run
# httpd works out of the box without any application specific config. That's why

COPY ./catalina.sh /
RUN chmod +x /catalina.sh  # copy your 'app' / entrypoint into the image

RUN groupadd -r tomcat \
    && useradd -r -g tomcat tomcat
# create a new user and group under which the container runs
RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat /tmp/  # change initial file permisisons. 
# So that our new user tomcat is allowed to access and fill the directory with files

USER tomcat  # switch the user under which the container runs

ENTRYPOINT ["/catalina.sh"]
```

`catalina.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/test  # create a dir
touch /tmp/yolo.txt  # and some files
touch /tmp/test/yolo2.txt  # to check the file permissions later on

while true; do echo "sleep"; sleep 2; done
# endless loop so that the container doesn't exit
```

To check the file permissions `exec` into the running container.

`docker exec -ti <container_name> bash`

[image]

Comment: `catalina.sh` isn't the App. It is the Startscript for Tomcat.                 
`catalina.sh run` starts tomcat in the foreground, displaying the logs on the console that you started it. Hitting Ctrl-C will terminate tomcat.

Comment: I guess it makes no difference. If you provide the ``USER`` directive in your ``Dockerfile`` you are running the container under this context. So when ``tomcat`` creates new files those will have the associated file permissions. Should be the same behaviour. Switch the image back to tomcat and give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Docker normally runs with root privilege, so I believe you must create a docker group (if it does not exist), and add the user (tomcat, in your case) to docker group.

See below how to add user to docker group:

Create the docker group.

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

Add your user to the docker group.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker tomcat
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

With this, I believe your problem can be solved.